# install 64-bit Visual Studio 2013 Professional on 32-bit machine

Tags: visual-studio-2013

What would happen if I tried to install the 64-bit version of Visual Studio 2013 Professional on a 32-bit machine?  I do not want to attempt doing this without some idea of what might happen.

Comment: The installation would fail. You can't run 64-bit software on a 32-bit-only OS.

Comment: There is no 64-bit Visual Studio version, and your question makes no sense. Of course you can't run software designed for 64-bit operating systems on a machine that doesn't support 64-bit software. You also can't run 64-bit software on a 32-bit operating system, for the same exact reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no 64-bit version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Is there the 64-bit version of Visual Studio?
http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0025/

> "... The main issue that does not let the developers to create the
>   64-bit version of Visual Studio is the amount of code that they would
>   need to port to a new platform. Porting the main studio's units will
>   force the programmers to port all the existing extension packages for
>   the tool as well. Benefits that will be gained from this high-cost
>   process are not very obvious at present. Most Visual Studio units will
>   not get any significant benefits after the port in comparison to their
>   32-bit versions while the requirements for physical memory the studio
>   will have while loading large projects might greatly rise because of
>   the increase of data structure sizes in the 64-bit version. But even
>   in the current Visual Studio versions, there is a problem related to
>   long loading time when opening large projects and the increase of
>   memory consumption will just make it worse. ..."